# How to make irregular CSS border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this with CSS:

[image]

It's easy to do with a white background, but how can I do this layout if it has a background image? This is what I mean:

[image]

I'm actually absolute positioning a div inside another:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="main-div-overlay-text">
    SOME TEXT
  </div>
  SOME TEXT HERE
</div>

.main-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.main-div-overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
legend {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
  <p>Text</p>
</fieldset>
```

To center the legend in Firefox, please use `<legend align="center">`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about this, works like a charm!