# How to put label on input like fieldset of HTML tag

Tags: html, input, label, border

I saw this question: [How to make irregular CSS border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414865/how-to-make-irregular-css-border)

and my question is that there is anyway to make input and label as this design somehow?
thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with changing the CSS file. With just using `<label>` and `<input>` and add some CSS class to it.

```css
.input-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
}
.input-field label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.input-field label .label-style {
  background: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.input-field input {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <label for="name"><span class="label-style">Full Name</span></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
</div>
```

For using it with SCSS you can refer on the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/nabilahzaid/pen/jOVLJWW)

Comment: this not work fine becouse of 'z-index: -1;' propriety seted in '.input-field input' css class.

Comment: @AlbertinoCarvalho can you elaborate?

Comment: i mean if you try to click to focus input, that not work becouse wrong css, but there is the correction: JUST remove 'z-index: -1' from input css and add "position: realative" to .label-style inside label css.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
i mean if you try to click to focus input, that not work becouse wrong css, but there is the correction: